# Calling method in background to get Facebook notifications and Twitter mentions

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, twitter, nsthread

I want to call a method in background to check for new notifications and mentions for Facebook and Twitter. How can I do this ? Currently I am calling methods on view will appear of main view only. If any notifications will be there then I have to show badge count also.Shall I use   NSThread For this purpose . I am not very much aware about NSThreads.

Please help

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSOperationQueue for your requirment. Which executes set of NSOperation objects concurrently. And Implement a delegate method to update badge.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1